# Redirecting to particular page from javascript in php function

Tags: php

I am calling javascript function from page1.php on submit button. In the  action attribute  I am redirecting to page2.php. In the if condition of JavaScript I want to redirect the control to page1.php if email is not validated in java script function.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the form from submitting to the action= page unless validated, call the javascript function like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return functionName()">
```

What that does is requests a positive return from your javascript function before it submits the form, so if it doesn't validate you can:

```
return false;
```

and show an error message to the user, the form won't submit in this case.

And if it does validate you can

```
return true;
```

And the form will submit as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to redirrect to another php script to do javascript validation. It needs to be said that javascript runs on client side. By redirrecting to another script you loose access to form input field with e-mail so in order to get in again in another script you must feed it to client be outputing in into html.

In stead of doing this you can easilly validat e-mail after clicking submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick=function(){
  if(!validateEmail()){
   alert("E-mail is not valid");
   return false;
  }
 }
};

function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
} 

</script>
```